# Mac OSX / cocoa - getting location path string with raw data for a NSPasteBoard item

Tags: macos, cocoa, copy, paste, nspasteboard

I have an app which allows me to drag items from my web browser to the app dock icon.

When I drag an image from the web and get is raw data with [pBoardItem dataForType:NSPasteboardTypePNG];
I get the raw image data which I need but I also need to know the location of the image form where it was taken (ie. http://www.somedomain.com/somedir/someimage.png ) OR if its local (/Users/somedude/photos/myphoto.png).

How do I get the path location information?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT** removed an erroneous comment I made regarding stringForType here]

Comment: You might want to try Pasteboard Inspector. It’s a nice utility that shows what exactly has been placed onto the pasteboard. Unfortunately I’m not able to find the official developer’s Web site.

Comment: @Bavarious: Apple has Clipboard Viewer as part of the Developer Tools (check the Utilities folder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing's on the pasteboard that wasn't put there by its owner (the app that copied to it).

Look for `NSFilenamesPboardType` and/or `NSURLPboardType` on the pasteboard.

If they aren't there, only an image was copied, without a path or URL. This is completely possible and valid, as in the case of a section of an image copied from Preview or an image editor, and it's also completely possible for an application to simply not put the path or URL on the pasteboard, so don't expect that an image will necessarily come with a path or URL.

> when I use the stringForType: function I only get public.png (the name pasteboard gave it temporarily).

Er? Are you saying that when you asked for a string for some type, the string you got back was `@"public.png"`?

If so, that has nothing to do with an image on the pasteboard; `@"public.png"` would be *the contents of the pasteboard*. Perhaps you had just copied “public.png” to the clipboard yourself?

If you meant that you retrieved a string for the type `@"public.png"`, (1) that isn't a temporary name, it's the [UTI](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/) for PNG, (2) you should use the named constants, such as `kUTTypePNG`, in preference to hard-coded literals, and (3) the value for that type should never be a string. I wouldn't expect to get anything useful from a `stringForType:` message with that type.

Comment: Apologies for the public.png thing. I misread something in my logs.

Comment: When I drag an image from my web browser to the finder. the image is stored in its original name which means the system got access to that filename (and maybe the original path). But I am unable to see the same item's filename in my app even when I use NSFilenamesPboardType... so where does the system get it from?

Comment: @user427034: Did you check `NSURLPboardType`? If that's not it, either, you can ask the pasteboard what types it has on it.

Comment: Yes thank you. The problem was that I needed to set the pasteboard  as the NSDragPboard so that it would get all of the forms of the dragged element rather than just one. pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];

Comment: @user427034: That gets the pasteboard that is already the drag pasteboard; it does not appoint a pasteboard you already have to be the drag pasteboard. Moreover, you shouldn't attempt to interact with a drag pasteboard except as a dragging source or a dragging destination; either way, you are handed the correct pasteboard to talk to.

Comment: Im only interacting with it for purposes of reading dragging source information. I am NOT creating a pasteboard for the purposes of writing to.

Comment: Maybe the original problem was based on how I get the pasteboard: I am using the function: -(void)contentService:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSData)userData error:(NSError *)error  which is called once the dragged object is released on my dock icon.

Comment: @Ziggizworth: Interesting; that's something I'd never heard of before. Where did you implement that method (not function)? Are you calling it, or is Cocoa calling it? Is there documentation or an article about that online?

Comment: I implement the method in my app delegate. here is Apple's documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html

Comment: @Ziggizworth: I've read the System Services Implementation Guide before; it doesn't talk about handling Dock drops, and makes only one reference to the application's delegate, which doesn't match what you're doing. Do you have something that talks about that specifically?

Comment: This is the tutorial I used: http://lethain.com/cocoa-drag-and-drop-text-into-the-dock-icon/  .It works but I have a problem where the method that is called as a result of a dock drop is of type -(void)contentService:(NSPasteboard*)pboard userData:(NSData*)userData error:(NSString **)error . which does not allow me to access the sender's NSDraggingInfo . Is there another way to  setup for and handle dock drops?

Comment: @Ziggizworth: Not that I know of, besides the document-handling machinery (which only works for file drops).

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation for what @Zigglzworth is doing to support Dock drops: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-1121328